# How do I make a robot with organic joints?

Tags: modeling, mesh, rigging

So I have this mesh I made I want to rig. As you can see I have already placed the armature. However I have been stuck trying to find ways to make the rest of the body stiff but have the joints move organically. Any solutions?
[image: So I have this mesh I made I want to rig.]

[image: As you can see I have already placed the armature. However I have been stuck trying to find ways to make the rest of the body stiff but have the joints move organically. Any solutions?]

[image]

Comment: you can assign weights to this parts

Comment: Parent the object With Empty Groups, then assign the vertices you want to the vertex groups you want with the Assign button, and weight paint when it is supposed to be organic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try *Bendy Bones* for the organic joints. This gives you a nice curvy shape.

[image: example animation]

*DEF-bendy-Joint* is the bendy bone. The others two are normal deformation bones and *CTL-Root* is a control bone to rotate, move, and scale the whole rig.

**There are two little flaws**

- *Bendy Bones* only work in Blender. If you plan to export the animation to a game engine or Three.js you need to convert them into a bone chain, use bone constraints and bake the animation.
- you need to rotate both bones (*DEF-Lower* and *DEF-bendy-Joint*) by 45° to bend the arm by 90°. Maybe you can add more control bones to make animation easier so that both DEF-bones will follow a control bone via *Copy Rotation* bone constraints.

The *Parent > Child* hierarchy is:

- *CTL-Root > DEF-Upper > DEF-bendy-Joint > DEF-Lower*

**Bendy Bone settings**

First, set *Viewport Display > Display As* of the armature to `B-Bone`. Then select the bone and increase the number of segments on the *Bone Properties* tab for this bone. In the example, I've set *Bendy Bones > Segments* to `10`. Because the bendy bone is part of a bone chain the *Start Handle* and *End Handle* will work with the default value `Automatic`. If bone gets twisted make sure all bones of the chain have the same *Bone Rolls*.
[image: bendy bone settings]

**Screenshots of the weights**

In the example, *Automatic Weights* were used. Then the rigid parts were weight painted with full weights. Alternatively, you can select the mesh parts in *Edit* mode and assign them to the corresponding vertex groups with weight 1.0 and weight 0.0 (or remove the unnecessary groups).

Make sure that for control bones the `[_]` *Deform* option is unchecked and no vertex group is created.

[image: weights part 1]

[image: weights part 2]

Comment: Thank you so much